# Why does this return statement throw an error in this python recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, return

I am practicing using recursive functions by summing all the elements in a list.

The function I made was:

```
def list_sum_recursive(input_list):

    #base case, list is empty
    if input_list == []:
        print("empty")
        return

    #recursive case
    else:
        #grab the first element
        head = input_list[0]
        del input_list[0]
        #return the sum of the head plus the sum of the rest of the list
        return head + list_sum_recursive(input_list)
```

This function throws this error however:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType

I did figure out the solution, making the base case `return 0` instead of just `return`.

But now I'm curious what the plain `return` was, or wasn't, doing to throw an error? And why in python, a language that is pretty flexible and forgiving, such a thing is an issue?

Comment: Being flexible and forgiving doesn't mean that the language should guess what you want. `return` on its own implicitly returns `None`. That is a rule of the language

Comment: Just returning returns `None` so when you do this `return head + list_sum_recursive(input_list)` you are adding `head` to `None` when the base case is reached. It's unforgiving because Python is a strongly typed language, which helps avoid some bugs that will happen if you assume `None` should automatically convert to zero..

Comment: All function calls in Python return a value.  If a bare `return` is executed, or if execution falls off the end of the function without executing a `return`, then they implicitly return `None`.  There is no concept of a "void" type that gives an error if an attempt is made to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't aware a bare return statement had a return type of None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to give you a more Pythonic version, I hope you don't mind.

```
def list_sum_recursive(input_list):

    #base case, list is empty
    if not input_list:
        return 0
    #return the sum of the head plus the sum of the rest of the list
    return input_list.pop(0) + list_sum_recursive(input_list)

print(list_sum_recursive([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Yeah, I would have used input_list[0] + list_sum_recursive([input_list[1:]). I feel a bit anxious modifying the list and using it in the same statement.

Comment: @Deepstop Yeah, slice looks like safer, and maybe more comfortable for more people.

Comment: I like both the popping and slicing method. Those are the types of things I need to start looking for in my code. It's very clean

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, don't return None in the first section. Return 0 instead.

```
def list_sum_recursive(input_list):

    #base case, list is empty
    if input_list == []:
    #    print("empty")
        return 0

    #recursive case
    else:
        #grab the first element
        head = input_list[0]
        del input_list[0]
        #return the sum of the head plus the sum of the rest of the list
        return head + list_sum_recursive(input_list)

print(list_sum_recursive([1,2,3]))
```

Running the program gives us

```
$ python test.py
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_sum_recursive(input_list):

    #base case, list is empty
    if input_list == []:
        print("empty")
        return

    #recursive case
    else:
        #grab the first element
        head = input_list[0]
        del input_list[0]
        #return the sum of the head plus the sum of the rest of the list
        x=list_sum_recursive(input_list)
        if(x==None):
            return head + 0
        else:
            return head+x
```

return 0 instead of none. or you can do this trick.